# How to draw indices in c++ Opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

Hello everybody i started using opengl with c++ and i figured out that the functions aren't the same as in java lwjgl.So let me get to my point.
I want to draw indices i looked a tutorial for drawing ibo's but it doesn't work.I get black screen only.

Window.cpp

```
#include "garbagecollector.h"
#include "window.h"

Window::Window(int width, int height, const std::string& title)
{
if(!glfwInit())
{
    GarbageCollector::collectGarbage();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 32);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL
*/
window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL);

if(!window){
    std::cerr << "Cannot create window!" << std::endl;
    GarbageCollector::collectGarbage();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to init GLEW!" << std::endl;
    GarbageCollector::collectGarbage();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
}
void Window::clear(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void Window::display(){
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
}

Window::~Window()
{
   std::cout << "window" << std::endl;
   glfwTerminate();
}
```

Mesh.h

```
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include "object.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <vector>


struct Vertex{

float position[3];

};

class Mesh : public Object
{
    public:
        Mesh();
        Mesh(Vertex vertecies[], int indices[]){
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glGenBuffers(2, &ibo);
        std::vector<unsigned int> indic;
        indic.push_back(0);
        indic.push_back(1);
        indic.push_back(2);

        size = indic.size();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * 4, &vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex) * 3,0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, &indic[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        }
        void bind(){
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        }
         void unbind(){
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        }
        void drawWithBindings(){
        bind();
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        unbind();
        }
        virtual ~Mesh();
    protected:
    private:
        GLuint vbo, ibo;
        unsigned int size;
};

#endif // MESH_H
```

Mesh.cpp

```
#include "mesh.h"

Mesh::Mesh()
{
    //ctor
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    std::cout << "mesh" << std::endl;
}
```

renderingEngine.h

```
#ifndef RENDERINGENGINE_H
#define RENDERINGENGINE_H

#include "game.h"
#include "mesh.h"
#include "shader.h"

class RenderingEngine : public Object
{
    public:
        RenderingEngine();
        void render();
        virtual ~RenderingEngine();
    protected:
    private:
        Mesh* mesh;
        Shader* shader;
        Vertex vertex[3];
};

#endif // RENDERINGENGINE_H
```

renderingEngine.cpp

```
#include "renderingengine.h"

RenderingEngine::RenderingEngine()
{
    vertex[0].position[0] = -1;
     vertex[0].position[1] = 0;
      vertex[0].position[2] = 0;
       vertex[1].position[0] = 1;
        vertex[1].position[1] = -1;
         vertex[1].position[2] = 0;
          vertex[2].position[0] = 1;
           vertex[2].position[1] = 1;
            vertex[2].position[2] = 0;

            int indices[3] = {0, 1, 2};
        shader = new Shader("vertex.vs", "fragment.fs");

    mesh = new Mesh(vertex, indices);
}

RenderingEngine::~RenderingEngine()
{
    std::cout << "renderingEngine" << std::endl;
}

void RenderingEngine::render(){
Game::getWindow().clear();
shader->bind();
mesh->drawWithBindings();
Game::getWindow().display();
}
```

Shader.h

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include "object.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

class Shader : public Object
{
    public:
        Shader();
        Shader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader){
        program = glCreateProgram();

        if(program == 0){
            std::cerr << "Cannot create program" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "pos");
        addVertexShader(vertexShader);
        addFragmentShader(fragmentShader);


        compileProgram();
        }
        void addVertexShader(const std::string& filename){
        addShader(loadShader(filename), GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        }
        void addFragmentShader(const std::string& filename){
        addShader(loadShader(filename), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        }
        void compileProgram(){
        glLinkProgram(program);
        GLint errorprogram = 0;
        char array[2048];
        int i = 0;
          glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &errorprogram);
        if(errorprogram == 0){
                glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 2048, &i, array);
            std::cout << array << std::endl;
        }
        glValidateProgram(program);
          glGetProgramiv(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &errorprogram);
        if(errorprogram == 0){
                glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 2048, &i, array);
            std::cout << array << std::endl;
        }
        }
        void bind(){
        glUseProgram(program);
        }
        virtual ~Shader();
    protected:
    private:
        void addShader(const std::string& source, GLuint type){
        GLint shader = glCreateShader(type);

        if(shader == 0){
            std::cerr << "Cannot shader program" << std::endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        const GLchar* h[1];
        h[0] = source.c_str();
        const GLint s[1] = {(GLint)source.size()};
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, h, s);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        GLint errorShader = 0;
        char array[2048];
        int i = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &errorShader);
        if(errorShader == 0){
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 2048, &i, array);
            std::cout << array << std::endl;
        }

        glAttachShader(program, shader);
        }
        std::string loadShader(const std::string& filename) const{
        std::string source = "";
        std::ifstream shader(filename);
        if(shader.is_open()){
            std::string line;
            while(!shader.eof()){
            while(getline(shader, line)){
            source += line;
            source += '\n';
            }
            }
        }
        return source;
        }
        GLuint program = 0;
};

#endif // SHADER_H
```

Shader.cpp

```
#include "shader.h"

Shader::Shader()
{
    //ctor
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
   std::cout << "shader" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I spotted everything, but here are a few issues that jumped out:

- Wrong argument to `glGenBuffers()`:

  ```
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glGenBuffers(2, &ibo);
  ```

  In the second call, you also want to generate only one buffer name, so it should be:

  ```
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
  ```
- Wrong size for vertex buffer:

  ```
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * 4, &vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  ```

  In the posted example, you only have 3 vertices. So this should be:

  ```
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * 3, &vertecies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  ```

  In reality, you would probably want to pass the number of vertices as an argument, or pass a `vector` instead of an array.
- Wrong value for stride:

  ```
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex) * 3,0);
  ```

  The 5th argument is the stride, which is the offset between vertices in bytes. In this case, that's the size of one vertex:

  ```
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
  ```
- Wrong size for index buffer:

  ```
  size = indic.size();
  ...
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, &indic[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  ```

  The `size` variable contains the number of indices. The argument to `glBufferData()` is the size in bytes:

  ```
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size * sizeof(GLuint), &indic[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  ```

Comment: I figured it out before you answered, but still thanks for the help.